# How can I compare 2 text lists for non identical matches in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have two lists. The first has 4000 records of suppliers and the second is a separate list with over 400000 suppliers. Each supplier is identified by name only and there may be different naming conventions.

I have already done the matching where an exact match exists. I then created two further lists;

1. contains the first word from the 4000 list
2. contains the first 2 words from the 4000 list

Is there a quick way that I can compare these two new lists to the 400000 list where it will highlight those items in the big list that contain the words in the 2 new lists I have created?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first word list and first 2 words list are one contiguous range called `Words` in the same book as your big list and your big list is in `ColumnA` starting at `A2`:

Select `A2`, Home, Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format, in Format values where this formula is true: enter:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(Words,A2))
```

Format, select your highlighting, OK, OK, Applies to `=$A$2:$A$400001`, Apply, OK.

For 400,000 names this is not tested.